# On e. preventDefault() and return false; fancy box get open

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, fancybox

Below is react code to open fancybox to confirm plan. if all the fields are validated then condition get's true and popup get open and if condition returns false then it prevent's the action and return false.
but in my case, after throwing error fancybox is getting open.

```
 componentDidMount:function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        helpers : {
            overlay : {
            closeClick : false
            }
        }
    });
 },
 validateIt: function(e,resolve,reject) {
    if(!this.validateAll()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } else {
        $(this.refs.submitFlightPlan).attr('href','#flightPlanPopup');
        $(this.refs.submitFlightPlan).trigger('click');
        resolve(true);
    }
},

validateFlightPlan: function(e) {
    this.state.mapError = '';
    this.state.message = '';
    this.setState(this.state);
    return new Promise(function(e,resolve,reject) {
        this.validateIt(e,resolve,reject);
    }.bind(this,e));
},
 render: function() {
    var PopupProps = {
        id: 'flightPlanPopup',
        header: 'Confirm plan?',
        message: 'Are you sure you want to save the Plan?',
        yesCallBack: this.reservePlan,
        isOkButton: false
    };
    return (
         <div className=" saveFlightPlan">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" className="btn primeBtn fancybox" ref = "submitFlightPlan" onClick = {this.validateFlightPlan.bind(this)}>Save Flight Plan</a>
            </div>
    );
 }
```

Comment: could you create a fiddle or something, reproducing the above error

Comment: Did you try debugging it? "validateIt" function is getting called or executed?

Comment: Yes this function is getting called.Actually i tried to run it without promise in that case also same thing is happening.

Comment: this `$('.fancybox').fancybox()` binds the selector `.fancybox` to fancybox plugin (it doesn't trigger fancybox though) and that is independent to your `preventDefault` event. You may need to rewrite your code and launch fancybox programmatically after a `click` event, where then you can apply the condition to prevent default behavior